# Run python script when txt file is changed

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am working on a home automation project with a Raspberry Pi 3 and I need to run some python scripts when a txt file changes. Is there a way to watch if the file is changed?
(Currently i use a python script which constantly opens the txt and checks if anything changed but its not efficient and it causes problems sometimes.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Watchdog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog/0.8.3) should tell you when there are file changes

Comment: Is the txt file changing predictible?

Comment: No, the client changes the value when he wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to report changes to a single file in the local directory called `foo.txt` you can use [watchdog](http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/) (which is a skin over inotify, or equivalent) like this:

```
from time import sleep
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        if event.src_path == "./foo.txt": # in this example, we only care about this one file
            print ("changed")

observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(Handler(), ".") # watch the local directory
observer.start()

try:
    while True:
        sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()

observer.join()
```